# Ошибка ndefined variable: request

Tags: laravel

есть метод в него приходят 2 параметра, но выдает ошибку `Undefined variable: request`, помогите решить проблему. Ругается на `$request->day`

```
public function showHall(Request $request)
{
    $hall = Hall::find($request->hall_id)->load(['schedule_hall' => function ($query) {
        $query->with('group')->where('day', $request->day);
    }]);

     return $hall;
}
```

Comment: А вы добавили `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`?

Comment: return $request->hall_id и return $request->day  выдает значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно прокинуть переменную в анонимную функцию (наследовать) с помощью `use`:

```
public function showHall(Request $request)
{
    $hall = Hall::find($request->hall_id)->load(['schedule_hall' => function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->with('group')->where('day', $request->day);
    }]);

     return $hall;
}
```